# TestNG Eclipse plug-in : How to change the name prefix of methods for [New -> TestNG Class]?

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

**Preferred**

```
@Test
public void testMethodName() {} // [New -> JUnit Test Case]
```

**than**

```
@Test
public void methodName() {} // [New -> TestNG Class]
```

I could achieve what I want by following steps :

1. `[New -> JUnit Test Case]`.
2. `Quick Assist` : `Convert to TestNG (Annotations)`

Any easier way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be pretty easy to add but I'm not sure how useful it really is: ultimately, you will want to rename your method to describe what it actually does as a test. For example, a method called `createAccount()` should probably be tested with a test method called `accountShouldBeCreated()`.

Also, a single method usually ends up being tested by more than one test method: `accountShouldBeCreated()`, `alreadyExistingAccountShouldNotBeAllowed()`, etc...